# 503 DNS Service Unavailable Error in Django when calling Google Data QnA API

Tags: python, django, api, google-api, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a Django web application where a user can search for data in a simple search bar. The user input is then used to call Google's Data QnA API, where the data is received from BigQuery and translated to natural language so that the user has a readable response.

However, when I attempt to call the API, I get a 503 Service Unavailable Error. When I call the API locally in my terminal, it works fine.

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud.dataqna import AutoSuggestionServiceClient, Question, QuestionServiceClient
from google.cloud import bigquery

client_options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint = f"us-dataqna-googleapis.com:443")
suggest_client = AutoSuggestionServiceClient(client_options = client_options)
questions_client = QuestionServiceClient(client_options = client_options)
bq_client = bigquery.Client()

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def response(request):

    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "[path to .json]"
    project = "[project name]"
    location = "us"
    scope = f"[scope of project]"

    parent = questions_client.common_location_path(project, location)

    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST.get("q")
        question = Question(scopes = [scope], query = title)
        question_response = questions_client.create_question(parent = parent, question = question)

        chosen_interpretation_index = 0

        question_response = questions_client.execute_question(name = question_response.name, interpretation_index = chosen_interpretation_index)
        chosen_interpretation = question_response.interpretations[chosen_interpretation_index]

        bigquery_job = chosen_interpretation.execution_info.bigquery_job
        job = bq_client.get_job(bigquery_job.job_id, bigquery_job.project_id, bigquery_job.location)
        job_results = job.result()

        headers = [schema_field.name for schema_field in job_results.schema]
        results = [dict(row) for row in job_results]

        return render(request,'response.html', { 'title' : title},
        { 'interpretation' : chosen_interpretation.human_readable.generated_interpretation.text_formatted },
        { 'sql' : chosen_interpretation.data_query.sql },
        { 'results' : results})

    else:
        return render(request, "index.html")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('response', views.response, name="response")
]
```

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dataqna_website")

SECRET_KEY = '[key]'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "[path to static file]"
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dataqna_website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dataqna_website.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Here is what I see after I type into the search bar in my application:

[503 DNS Service Unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmDTZ.png)

Comment: Is the route to the api actually working when not using Django ?

Comment: @FrédéricPerron Yes, it is working outside of Django when I call it in my local Python environment.